# ios show image on qlpreviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, qlpreviewcontroller

i am trying to preview image on qlpreviewcontroller.
i had implemented these methods.

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller
{
    return 1;
}


- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController: (QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    // Break the path into its components (filename and extension)

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imageFilePath];
}
```

but problem is that i had images saved in database in form of base64.
qlpreviewcontroller needs filepath to display item.

i have only option for this is to save that image in document than preview it from that path.
but is their any better option. that i can display that uiimage directly ...

Comment: There is no other option, you will need filepah for image saved in document directory.